# Gauss Law in toy model

Tags: gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics

In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqgNrVTQ4yM&t=4453s prof. Seiberg states that the Gauss Law for the action
$$S=\int \phi da,$$
where $\phi$ is a scalar field and $a$ is a $U(1)$ gauge field over a two dimensional spacetime, can be obtained by varying with respect to the gauge condition $a_0=0$, yielding $\partial_1\phi=0$. This is easy to see from the coordinate expression
$$S=\int d^2x \phi(\partial_0 a_1-\partial_1 a_0).$$

I was wondering, how can I see this from the Hamiltonian perspective? If one rewrites
$$S=\int d^2x(\phi\partial_0a_1+\partial_1\phi a_0)+\int d^2x\partial_1[\phi a_0],$$
the first terms does seem to suggest that $\phi$ is the momentum conjugate to $a_1$ and then $\partial_1\phi=0$ is a constraint with Lagrange multiplier $a_0$. However, does the boundary term here produce issues? I guess the same question can be asked of Electrodynamics on spaces with boundaries.

More generally, in this particular case we saw we could find the constraint by differentiating with respect to the gauge condition since the gauge condition was fixing the Lagrange multiplier of the constraint. How generic is this procedure?

Finally, this toy model and simple generalizations were discussed through the lecture above. Does anyone know of a reference were I can learn more about this model (I don't even know its name) and other simple quantum field theory models. I am particularly attracted to them since you can compute everything explicitly.